# Is it possible to delete a Graph3D in vis js?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I cannot find a way to delete a Graph3D object in [visjs](http://visjs.org/docs/graph3d/), since there is no `destroy()` method. I'd appreciate it if you could come up with some fresh ideas.

Answer (score 0):

When you are done with the object, why not set it (and any variables that reference it) to null?

```
obj = null;
```

It will then eventually be garbage collected and the memory freed up.

Or:

```
 if (obj != undefined){
     obj.destroy();
 }
```

The above works fine in Meteor.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work, since when I choose another graph type to display, the new graph is added below the first one. Only when I choose the Graph3D the container gets cleaned up

Comment: Are you using a different object name for the other graph type?

Comment: No I'm using the same object name

Comment: If you can put your code in a GitHub repo, I can take a look.

Comment: Hey guys, did you ever figure this out?